# amcharts create only 3 series from combo data

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have this function in amcharts4 that creates a series for each year of data, is there a way to put a combo so that only 3 series can be put on the graph but in each combo say which years to show? I have more than 10 years of data and I don't want to put it all on the graph
I use php and javascript. I get data from a json.

```
chart.dataSource.url = "ejemplodatos.php";
```

Thanks

```
function createAxisAndSeries(field, name, opposite, bullet) {
  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  if(chart.yAxes.indexOf(valueAxis) != 0){
    valueAxis.syncWithAxis = chart.yAxes.getIndex(0);
  }
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "mesdia";
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  
  series.name = name;
  series.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.minBulletDistance = 10;
  //series.disabled=true 
  var interfaceColors = new am4core.InterfaceColorSet();
  
  switch(bullet) {
    case "triangle":
      valueAxis.renderer.line.disabled = true; //disables axis line
      valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true; //disables labels
      valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;  //disables grid
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
      bullet.width = 1;
      bullet.height = 1;
      bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
      bullet.verticalCenter = "middle";
      
      var triangle = bullet.createChild(am4core.Triangle);
      triangle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      triangle.strokeWidth = 2;
      triangle.direction = "top";
      triangle.width = 1;
      triangle.height = 1;
      break;
 
    default:
      var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
      bullet.circle.stroke = interfaceColors.getFor("background");
      bullet.width = 1;
      bullet.height = 1;
      bullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;
      break;
  }
  
  valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
  valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
  valueAxis.renderer.line.stroke = series.stroke;
  valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = series.stroke;
  valueAxis.renderer.opposite = opposite;
  valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
}
createAxisAndSeries("a2024", "2024", false, "default");
createAxisAndSeries("a2023", "2023", false, "default");


function toggleAxes(ev) {
  var axis = ev.target.yAxis;
  var disabled = true;
  axis.series.each(function(series) {
    if (!series.isHiding && !series.isHidden) {
      disabled = false;
    }
  });
  axis.disabled = disabled;
}
```

Comment: I dont see any PHP or MySQL to justify using those tags?

Comment: I create my json with mysql and php. The file chart.dataSource.url = "ejemplodatos.php"; And the combo with the differents year also. But I don't know to select the year I have to draw in the series.  createAxisAndSeries("a2024", "2024", false, "default");